# How to get fields in a firestore document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on some Cloud functions that works with Firestore. I am trying to get a list of fields of a specific document. For example, I have a document reference from the `even.data.ref`, but I am not sure if the document contains the field I am looking at. I want to get a list of the fields' name, but I am not sure how to do it. 
I was trying to use `Object.keys()` method to get a list of keys of the data, but I only get a list of number (0, 1...), instead of name of fields.
I tried to use the `documentSnapShot.contains()` method, but it seems doesn't work.

```
exports.tryHasChild=functions.firestore.document('cities/{newCityId}')
.onWrite((event) =>{
  if (event.data.exists) {
    let myRef = event.data.ref;
    myRef.get().then(docSnapShot => {
      if (docSnapShot.contains('population')) {
        console.log("The edited document has a field of population");
      }
    });
```

Comment: post your code.. that helps us to help you with providing a better answer. Welcome to SO and finish the tour ;-)

Comment: For example: 
exports.tryHasChild = functions.firestore.document('cities/{newCityId}').onWrite((event) =>{


  if (event.data.exists) {
    let myRef = event.data.ref;

    myRef.get().then(docSnapShot => {
        if (docSnapShot.contains('population')) {
          console.log("The edited document has a field of population");
        }
  });

Comment: Please post it in your question with the correct formatting. Remove it from the comment as well. You can self edit..no problems with that ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [documentation on using Cloud Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) shows, you get the data of the document with `event.data.data()`.

Then you can iterate over the field names with JavaScript's `Object.keys()` method or test if the data has a field with a simple array check:

```
exports.tryHasChild=functions.firestore.document('cities/{newCityId}')
.onWrite((event) =>{
  if (event.data.exists) {
    let data = event.data.data();
    Object.keys(data).forEach((name) => {
      console.log(name, data[name]);
    });
    if (data["population"]) {
      console.log("The edited document has a field of population");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you similar things in Swift? Thanks

Comment: It seems possible from a quick search:https://www.google.com/search?q=swift+iterate+over+properties+of+object