# Firestore how to get keys from firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using below query, I can get the document and doc.data().name to get the value for the key 'name'. I would like to get all the keys in that document. How can I get that?

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());

//**I want to get all keys in the document here.**

    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on my example from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372476/how-to-get-fields-in-a-firestore-document/48373232#48373232), you can do:

```
docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        let json = doc.data();
        console.log("Document data:", json);
        console.log("Document keys:", Object.keys(json));
        Object.keys(json).forEach((name) => {
          console.log(name, json[name]);
        });
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In firebase, If you want to access the value of a key in a document inside your collection. Let's say key "name" or "email". Use the code below:

```
searchSnapshot.docs[index]["name"].data()
searchSnapshot.docs[index]["email"].data()
```

Note: I used search box here, you might have a different plugin to implement.